# How to get all the rows in my results as opposed to only 100 rows?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell(Integrated) version.

When I right click on any table and select 'Query Window' I am able to write code to return values from an Oracle database. But when I run it, **I get only 100 rows of the results**.

**How do I get all the rows of results**? Is there an option I can check or uncheck to achieve that?

Comment: I've added an oracle tag for you.  I know that you don't care about the language, but if you add a tag for the language you wish to use going forward, you will get more eyes on your problem (C++ especially)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Visual Studio, but I suppose you need just press PgDown or End button in results table. Where PgDown - fetch next 100 rows. End - fetch all rows.At least SQL Navigator works that way.